# How do I construct LocalDateTime from month and year only

Tags: java, jodatime

I have the following String "November 2013". How do I construct a LocalDateTime object from it ?

This what I have tried but does not work

```
LocalDateTime.parse(form.getSelectedMonthAndYear(),DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM yy"));
```

The `MM yy` patern works only for my `DatePicker`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this pattern(`MMM yyyy`) for the String "November 2013".

```
LocalDateTime.parse(form.getSelectedMonthAndYear(),DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMM yyyy"));
```

Comment: Thanks. It just make me wonder why some library uses different pattern for datetime formatting.

Comment: You would have used the very same pattern even if you're to parse it using the `SimpleDateFormat`.